# Cannot insert datasheet into form (Access Project)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Following the instruction found here: [Insert a datasheet into a form](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HA100968051033.aspx?pid=CH102920981033) I get an error when trying to insert a query as a datasheet in an Access Project (SQL Server 2005 backend)

> The form name you entered doesn't follow Microsoft Office Access object-naming rules

I selected the view `View.dbo.viewname` from the dropdown in 'Source Object' and the above error occurred as soon as I did that. If I take off `View.dbo.viewname`, it saves, but then I can't see the datasheet data. I want to add the view as it contains subdatasheets.

Wrapping it in brackets, e.g. `[View.dbo.viewname]` or `View[.]dbo[.]viewname` (as dots are apparently not allowed, although the link suggests otherwise) doesn't help

Comment: Don't know if that will work, as ODBC data sources are PC specific and there are a large number of potential users. Hence the reason for doing an Access Project rather than database (no external dependencies). I used the dropdowns that Access provided, then it complained (which doesn't make any sense).  Don't have access to project at moment to check though.

Comment: Plus, can you update with ODBC linked tables and datasheet entry?

Comment: Are there any options for non-ODBC data sources, perhaps MS SQL directly. It really doesn't have to be ODBC.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do updates through ODBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never managed to get it to work. Perhaps due to being an Access Project (ADP) rather than database (MDB). Had to resort to creating forms (with nested subforms) instead of datasheets to get what I wanted.

Also, nested forms (two levels down) don't seem to work in Access 2007, but do in 2003, so had to go back to that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit deceptive; **"Query.foobar"** is OK, but **"Query.foo.bar"** is not.

MS Access seems to be using that first portion as a way of deciding if your record source is a Query or Table, and the period (.) is a delimiter, *and you seem to be limited to one*. This is probably one of the reasons why it is disallowed in object names.

It looks like you are accessing the view directly instead of creating a link to the view in the tables tab/list (you shouldn't even be able to create a table/query named like that). Perhaps this is available in ms-access-2007, I'm not familiar enough with it.

In any case, my solution would be to create a table link to `View.dbo.viewname` and rename it (if MS Access doesn't do that for you by it self) to `dbo_viewname`. This will let you set the data source to `Table.dbo_viewname`.

**Edit:**
To create the table link,

1. go to the Tables tab/list on the database window
2. right click in the list
3. Select `link tables...`
4. Change `Files of Type` to `ODBC databases` (I assume you already have an ODBC connection set up. If not, how are you getting to your data?).
5. Switch to the `Machine Data Source` tab
6. Select your data source.
7. Click OK
8. Select the tables/views you want.
9. Click OK

The links will show up in your tables tab/list as with arrows pointing at little green globe.

Don't type the data source in. Use the pull down, that will guarantee you are using the right syntax.

Comment: How do you go about creating a table link?

Comment: 'Table.dbo.tablename', 'Table.tablename' and 'tablename' all fail as well (it lets me put 'tablename' in, but nothing appears)

Comment: It is an Access Project (ADP), so no ODBC data source... Want to run this for multiple users (100+), so no access to File or Machine Data Sources. Can be opened in Access 2007 and 2003

Comment: Basically, you need to find a way to have the the view represented to MS Access without the period in its name. Even as linked in an ADP, you should be able to rename them.

Comment: You keep saying that ODBC has issues that it doesn't. You don't need a DSN to link to an ODBC data source from an Access MDB -- DSN-less connections work just fine.

Comment: In Access 2007, I add the linked table via External Data > Import > More > ODBC Database. After this, it prompts for a DSN source. Plus it is an ADP, not an MDB

Comment: Fair enough. However, the must be a way to rename that view (on the MS Access side) to something more reasonable. You can do it with tables. Just go to Object->Database Diagram and edit the table's properties (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP030840371033.aspx). There MUST be something similar for views.